# The download manager loses its access to the Internet after working for a while in ubuntu 23.10.1

Tags: networking, software-installation, configuration, firewall, 23.10

I use download manager in Ubuntu but after a while it works fine and the internet access is blocked!

I tested `Free Download Manager` and `Xtreme Download Manager` both of them at first work correctly but after some time those doesn't work correctly

[image]

**Note :** When i used `fdm` it's return me `NetWork access is faild` but it's deleted and i don't have image that error

How can fix this problem?

Comment: I am also having some issues with this version of XDM. However I do not have connection issue. Rather, XDM is not able to complete video download because of some ffmpeg error after it has downloaded the parts of the video file.

Comment: @FaisalAslam I tested **fdm** and that return `NetWork access faild`. it's happend every file when i started download. i think its can be my firewall because when pc in sleep mode download be continue

Answer (score 0):

I tried XDM snap version and got this instead.

```
[xdm-10:25:23] Loading config...
[xdm-10:25:23] Application_Startup
Unhandled exception. GLib.GException: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.78" (uid=1000 pid=4398 comm="/snap/xdman/60/opt/xdman/xdm-app" label="snap.xdman.xdman (enforce)") interface="org.gtk.Actions" member="DescribeAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="xdm.app" (uid=1000 pid=1699 comm="/opt/xdman/xdm-app --background" label="unconfined")
   at GLib.Application.Register(Cancellable cancellable)
   at XDM.GtkUI.Program.Main(String[] args)
Aborted (core dumped)
```